# Is it possible to search for class attributes of a template in the wysiwyg editor of xwiki?

Tags: xwiki

If I try to create a link to another xwiki page I can search for the xwiki titles of the pages:

[create a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSVTc.png)

For some use case I created a template with a template class and some attributes. Is it possible to search for such an attribute when creating a link to a xwiki page of that template type via the wysiwyg editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that's not possible from the WYSIWYG. You can use the wiki search to find the page name though.